# Why doesn't Vim substitute the text matched by a second branch of a pattern?

Tags: vim

Given the text: `ab`

Why does this command `:s/a\|b//` only substitute the text `a`?

But when you search with pattern `a\|b`, both the text `a` and `b` are matched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should append /g , to substitute each matched pattern, or it will substitute the first matched pattern.

```
:s/a\|b//g
```

You can find the following information through :help substitute

> [g]     Replace all occurrences in the line.  Without this argument,
>           replacement occurs only for the first occurrence in each line.

Comment: Oh, I hate my carelessness with a passion!